# while vs setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have the following array to monitor the widgets to be initiated by an app I'm working on:

```
widgets = [{
 selector: ".table",
 init: function() {...}
},
{
 selector: ".anothertable",
 init: function() {...}
}]
```

Each init function is invoking a plugin. When a plugin has finished its tasks
it pushes the selector (e.g ".table") to another array called "readyWidgets"

Now the question is this:

How can I tell once all selectors nested under the primary widgets array
are present in readyWidgets array?

I'm kind of having a blackout, although I have a solution, I think there is a better one I'm missing.

This is what I came up with:

```
init: function() {
    // this will hold each widget selector
    // and look for it later in readyWidgets array
    var widgetsPending = []

    // initialize each widget in widgets array
    // (only if the selector matches at least one element)
    this.widgets.forEach(function(widget) {
        $(widget.selector).length && widgetsPending.push(widget.selector) && widget.init()
    }, this)

    // use setInterval to check if all values in widgetsPending array
    // are present within this.readyWidgets
    var that = this
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        // temporary just to make sure the interval is cleared
        console.log(that.readyWidgets)

        // if a value in widgetsPending is not found in 
        // that.readyWidgets, pageReady will be marked false
        var pageReady = true
        widgetsPending.forEach(function(selector) {
            if (that.readyWidgets.indexOf(selector) == -1) {
                pageReady = false
            }
        })

        // if widgetsReady is true, clear the interval
        pageReady && clearInterval(interval)
    }, 300)     
}
```

If you have any suggestions on how improve this, do tell :)

Comment: Use `deferred`s and `promise`s. You can then `$.wait` for all to complete and fire code at that point.

Comment: `while` should not be an option. It will block your code execution.

Comment: TrueBlueAussie is right, using jQuery deferred and `$.when` or `$.wait` is the way forward here. How can you tell when any individual widget is ready so it is pushed onto `readyWidgets`?

Comment: I actually meant `$.when`... (not `$.wait`) should have checked my typing :)

Comment: @Anduril each plugin "declares" it's ready. When a plugin is finished, it pushes its selector to readyWidgets. the code does work using this flow..

Comment: I haven't used jQuery promises, but I would have recommended to use [Kris Kowal's Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).  Since you're using jQuery I think TrueBlueAussie's suggestion is the way to go.  The Q documentation may be worth a read, to understand the concept of promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var loadOperations = [];

objects.forEach(function (obj) {
    var loadComplete = $.Deferred();

    loadOperations.push(loadComplete);

    // long running async function call. this function can return deferred or promise as well
    obj.someLongRunningEGLoadOperation(function() { // async function complete callback
        loadComplete.resolve();
    });
});

$.when.apply($, loadOperations).done(function () {

    // do something then all long running operations are completed

});
```

Comment: I noticed the first parameter is "$", does this mean '$' holds the async operations being preformed by jQuery or jQuery plugins for that matter?

Comment: $ ia a shortcut for jQuery - root object representing jQuery library

Comment: I know that.. I was wondering why use $.when.apply() vs $.when(), but I just noticed it was a simply a short hand to apply loadOperations as the function args..